# Delphi 10 FireDAC, TFDConnection doesn't connect when program runs as a service

Tags: delphi, service, firedac

I try to connect to a Firebird Database, using the ODBC DriverId from TFDConnection.

When my program runs as a normal application on the desktop I have no problem connecting.

When my program runs as a service it will not connect.

```
FDConnection1.Params.Clear;    
FDConnection1.Params.Add('DriverID=ODBC');
FDConnection1.Params.Add('DataSource=FB-Database');
FDConnection1.Connected := TRUE;
```

The TFDConnection raises an exception, when running as a service:

```
[FireDAC] [Phys] [ODBC] [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] The name of the data source was not found and no default driver was specified
```

Comment: You're most probably missing your data source configuration in the System DSN (that's where NT services look up for data sources).

Comment: @Victoria,  that sounds right.  In addition, ISTR that a service will be unable to access any resource via a UNC path, even if the path resolves to a local resource.

Comment: @MartynA, my point was related to ODBC Data Source Administrator and their [data source types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/admin/about-drivers-and-data-sources). It's not described in the manual but the dialog describes the usage for services in the System DSN tab.

Comment: @Victoria, thanks, this works, putting it in the System DSN.

Comment: Glad that it helped you! Feel free to answer with some decent screenshot where to setup this. I would do that, but my Windows is in spanish :)